# There is a function $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$ such that $a$ is a limit point of $X$, $f$ does not have limit at $a$, but $|f(x)|$ has a limit at $a$.

Tags: real-analysis

Is this true? There is a function $f:X \to \Bbb{R}$, $X \subseteq \Bbb{R}$, such that $a$ is a limit point of $X$, $f$ does not have limit at $a$, but $|f(x)|$ has a limit at $a$

If it did not said that $a$ is a limit point, then $f(x) = \dfrac{x}{|x|}$ would be an example with $a=0$.

But since $a \in X'$, I think it is false: There is no function such that this happens. But I do not know how to prove this.

Any help would be appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: I'm very confused. The example you gave is fine. You have $X = \Bbb{R} \setminus \{0\}$ and $a = 0$, which is a limit point of $X$. What's the problem?

Comment: Isn´t $0$ just a right-limit point and a left-limit point?

Comment: What is the definition of limit point you're using?

Comment: $a$ is a limit point if every neighborhood of $a$ contains some point different than $a$... Then is it true that every right limit point is a limit point? and also every left limit point is a limit point?

Comment: If these terms mean what I think they mean, then yes: it doesn't matter if the nearby points lie to the left or right (or both) of $a$, the fact is that any neighbourhood $(a - \varepsilon, a + \varepsilon)$ contains points in $X$.

Comment: Oh, I see it now. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Take $X=[0,1]$ and
$$
f(x) = \frac{\sin(1/x)}{|\sin(1/x)|}
$$
for $x\to 0$.

Answer (score 1):

Let $X=\Bbb R.$ Let $f(x)=+1$ when $x\in \Bbb Q.$ Let $f(x)=-1$ when $x\in \Bbb R$ \ $\Bbb Q.$ Let $a$ be any point in $\Bbb R.$

Answer (score 0):

What about the following? Let $C$ be the unit circle without the $x$-axis, and let $f: C \to \mathbb{R}$ with $f(x, y) = y/|y|$. Then $P = (0, 0)$ is a limit point, and $$\lim_{Q \to P} |f(Q)| = 1$$
while the limit without the absolute value is ill-defined, since approaching from below the $x$-axis gives $-1$ and approaching from above the $x$-axis gives $1$.